# how to setup Table Rate Shipping $1 for every 1KG extra

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, shipping-methods, magento-community, table-rates

I'm trying to use Table Rate Shipping. My shipping rate are from 0KG to 15KG is $30 and I add $1 for every 1KG but in Table Rate Shipping do I have to add manually. Is there any way to make this dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

This is default not possible. Due to the fact that you can only choose Fixed weight X destination or price X destination.

But this might be a solution for you. Each cheap and you can set the price for a kg. or in this case a multiplier per KG.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ship-per-weight.html